# How can i run Wifi direct in my andrioid ICS tablet?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wifi-direct

i have an **android ICS** tablet (no bluetooth) , I want to share files wirelessly...
but in ICS wifi direct is not there.I heard that **wifi direct** is not any hardware plugin - it is based on OS and can be run in android ICS.
So please if u know tell me *step by step instruction.*
...

Answer (score 0):

Install and run [ES File explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) on both Android devices and connect them both to one Wi-Fi access point. Long press on the file and use `Send` option and choose scan. After some lag the target device will be listed and just selecting it will prompt for confirmation on the target device. Once confirmation is accepted, the transfer will take place.

You can see ES File Explorer's [help](http://www.estrongs.com/eshelp/en/network.htm) page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is sharing between multiple Android devices (which is what WiFi Direct is for, amongst others), you might want to take a look at apps like [SuperBeam](http://www.appbrain.com/app/SuperBeam-WiFi-Direct-Share/com.majedev.superbeam) or [Fast File Transfer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Fast-File-Transfer/com.floriandraschbacher.fastfiletransfer). Both are directly connecting two devices (which both have the app installed) via WiFi, without any intermediate.